# How to get SUCCESS in SqlSensor(Airflow) when my sql throws me a null value

Tags: airflow

How I can get SUCCESS value in SqlSensor(Airflow) when my sql throws me a NULL value and if it gets some records then FAIL? Do I need to write my own SqlSensor, if so, then can you guide me how to do this?
my SqlSensor:

```
sensor = SqlSensor(
    task_id='check_for_data_in_table',
    conn_id = O_CONN_ID,    
    timeout=3200,
    poke_interval=120,
    sql="""
      select column_c from test_table where column_b = to_date(trunc(sysdate))
    """,
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: I've also added some parameters in my task sensor = SqlSensor(     task_id='check_for_data_in_table',     conn_id = O_CONN_ID,         timeout=3200,     poke_interval=120,     sql="""       select column_c from test_table where column_b = to_date(trunc(sysdate))     """,    ** fail_on_empty=False**,     **allow_null=True**,     dag=dag)  and it didn't help at all

Comment: I've decided to add **case** **when** in SQL, so when I receive null value my case will give me 1 and 0 if not

Answer (score 1):

You could define `success` and `failure` callbacks to do this.

If `success` is defined then the sensor will keep trying till the callback returns true.

If `failure` is defined the sensor will stop (with error) the moment failure callback returns true.

Doc: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.1/_api/airflow/sensors/sql/index.html#airflow.sensors.sql.SqlSensor

```py
def success_fn(first_cell):
    print(f"Value of first_cell: {first_cell}")
    return first_cell is None


def failure_fn(first_cell):
    print(f"Value of first_cell: {first_cell}")
    return first_cell is not None


sensor = SqlSensor(
    task_id='check_for_data_in_table',
    conn_id="sensor_test",
    success=success_fn,
    failure=failure_fn,
    sql="""
      select None;
    """,
    dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query would return true if no rows are present

```
select count(*) = 0 
from test_table
where column_b = to_date(trunc(sysdate))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select case when count(column_c) = 0 then 1
            else 0
           end chk
      from test_table 
     where column_b = to_date(trunc(sysdate));
```