# Airflow SqlSensor

Tags: python, airflow

I have a dag that checks if a database is in recovery mode. The task is a sqlsensor, and I'm struggling to get this correct. I want to check every 5 minutes to see if a database is in recovery mode or not. The sql query will return one row, either false or true. I want to mark the task as Failed if it returns False and Success if it return True. The problem is that this code for some reason is continuously checking the database every second, it seems the cacthup argument is not working and is backfilling everything. I set the poke_interval differently for 5 minutes but this does not work as I expect. I also don't know how to handle the parameters `success` and `failure` in this case when the sql query returns `false` and `true`.

```
from airflow.sensors.sql import SqlSensor
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


# Define the DAG
default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 7, 15),
    'catchup': False,
}

dag = DAG(
    'database_monitor',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='*/10 * * * *'  # Runs every 10 minutes
)

check_db_alive = SqlSensor(
    task_id="check_db_alive",
    conn_id="evergreen",
    sql="SELECT pg_is_in_recovery()",
    #failure= lambda x: x == 'false',
    poke_interval= 60 * 5,
    timeout = 60 * 2,
    mode = "reschedule",
    dag=dag
)

check_db_alive
```

Comment: success and failure callbacks are just functions that return a bool. example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76714726/4593654

Comment: Sensors running in poke mode will not release the worker till the sensor becomes success. You could check task log to see if the sensor is actually poking every 1 second, most probably it won't.  If you want your worker to be released then you could use the `reschedule` mode.